# Where has the “Related questions” feed gone?

Tags: feature-request, support, related-questions

When reading a post, there used to be a feed, on the right of the page, of “Related questions”.

It was helpful and enjoyable (especially on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)). For a few days now, I don’t see it, no matter the device I use (laptop, Ipad, phone).

Is it me or that feature has been suppressed? The latter would be unfortunate.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it's still a duplicate.  And the original question has a large bounty on it.

Comment: The question is similar. Sorry, I saw it after posting. However, it does not seem to have an answer so far.

Comment: @Ollie Of course it is (and I VTCed here). The auto generated comment is just a bit misleading though.

Comment: @A.B. The status tag says that the dev team is investigating it ATM.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not at the moment, actually. Review tag means the bug/request is on their list, we can't know when a dev will actually get to check and fix it. Can take hours, days, weeks, months, or years.

Comment: Actually, the [tag:status-review] was added by an MSE mod back on July 13th. It's why I added the bounty. It is unclear what SE knows or is doing about it. I think linked duplicates can only help raise awareness, so I'm up-voting this one too.

Comment: @ColleenV sure, same here. Duplicates are useful. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask sorry I forgot the `@` -that was directed mostly toward πάντα ῥεῖ's comment :)

Comment: @ColleenV [You are welcome](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=8462934#8462934).